# GCP BigQuery: Mirror BigQuery table in other project to another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, replication, google-cloud-pubsub

We have an use where a third party application is updating several BigQuery tables (ex.table-A) in a GCP project (my-project-a) at regular intervals. This project is not accessible to end users. We need to replicate these tables (table-B) to another GCP Project (my-project-b) as soon as the the table-A is updated by the third party application. Requirement is to ensure that the tables in the two projects are always in sync. What is the best option to achieve this?

We tried the following

1. BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not work as minimum frequency between copy jobs is 12 hours

Comment: Did you investigate materialized views (but the projects, source and destination, must be in the same project) or dataset replica https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-replication ? And if you share the data only for reading them, you can simply share a view of your data.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere. We evaluated MVs but as you noted that does not work. We also tested Cloud Functions/Scheduler and Pub/Sub but that is also at a schedule and is not acceptable to the users. Thanks for note on Dataset Replication - I will test this feature.

Comment: Can you explain why the user need materialized data on their side? Usually, there is only one source of truth that share the data to another consumer. Views are made for that. Sometime, to increase the performances, materialized views are better, more expensive but better. For cross region issue, replicas are made for that. To share views externally and in industrial mode, Analytics Hub is designed for that. For low confidence sharing, Data Clean Room is coming. But, whatever the solution, the master data are still kept in a single place and when duplicated, it's only in read only.

Comment: Thanks, @guillaumeblaquiere. MVs were one of the options we looked at. Scenario is: Third party application is writing to Inbound ProjectA.DatasetA (tables and views) which are not accessible to end-users. We need to mirror these tables and views in another ProjectB.DatasetB (accessible to users) and there should be no time lag meaning that we cannot replicate at some predefined schedule. We are testing various options to do this and we have tried the options I mentioned. Dataset Replication also will not work because both Projects are in the same region. What option would you suggest?

Comment: Yes, you have to share the data as soon you have it in the project A. So create a view in projectB, with filter on only the data available to the customer. And create an authorized view on project A to allow view in project B to query the data. Like that, the data are immediately available for the projectB's users, without materialization (you don't need that, or I missed something in your requirement). https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere. We will test this and update. Thanks for your help.